# as.numeric() in R with Warning Message: NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, warnings

I have imported date from excel and have tried defined the character variable into numeric variable so then I will be able to use *K-means* clustering.

When defining the numeric variable using `as.numeric()` function in `R` the following error is being prompted and I have checked the raw data and there are no NAs in my raw data.

```
The following objects are masked from db (pos = 3):

    CityName, ContractStart, CustomerID, DwellingType, MonthlyDataUsage, Nationality, Num_HYB, Num_PP, Num_PRE,
    OfferName, ServiceName, SubscriberID

> sapply(db,class)
    SubscriberID       CustomerID    ContractStart        OfferName      ServiceName     DwellingType      Nationality 
       "numeric"        "numeric"      "character"      "character"      "character"      "character"      "character" 
        CityName           Num_PP          Num_HYB          Num_PRE MonthlyDataUsage 
     "character"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"        "numeric"

> db.ServiceName.num <- as.numeric(db$ServiceName)
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

Can someone help me please why am I getting this **warning error** please?

Comment: You have data which is not a string representation of a number.  Check your data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - Service Name is made up of the following 3: "Product A"; "Product B" and "Product C" why can't it be a string representation of a number?

Comment: Hi Lise. The function `as.numeric()` takes a string such as `"84"` and returns the actual number 84, so you can't use it to convert arbitrary strings to numbers. If you want to do this you could try converting to a factor first. Try `as.numeric(factor(db$ServiceName))`

Comment: @AllanCameron seem to have worked thank you so much